# Pointer to array deference

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int (*ptr)[3] = a;
    printf("%d %d \n ", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
    ++ptr;
    printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
    ptr++;
    printf("%d %d\n", (*ptr)[1], (*ptr)[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone explain why in first printf, (*ptr)[1],(*ptr)[2] is giving 2,3 as    output?

isn't `(*ptr)[1]` output should be 4 and `(*ptr)[2]` output should  0?

is it means that `(*ptr)[1]` is equal to `ptr[0][1]` and
`(*ptr)[2]` means `ptr[0][2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int (*ptr)[3]` defines a pointer to an array of 3 elements.

Hence the access `(*ptr)[1]` refers to the 2nd element of the array where ptr is pointing now (in eg. it points to location contatining 2). Think of it as a matrix. Ptr points to the row (in eg it will point to the location containing 4).

Now about `ptr++`. Compiler knows that ptr is pointing to an array of 3 int elements. So the step `ptr++` increments the pointer by `3 * sizeof(int)`. In our matrix analogy, ptr is now pointing to next row.

yes your view of "is it means that (*ptr)[1] is equal to ptr[0][1] and (*ptr)[2] means ptr[0][2]? " is correct

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to keep in mind that

```
int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

is the same as

```
int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

and

```
int (*ptr)[3] = a;
```

is the same as

```
int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0];
```

Now, `(*ptr)[1]` first dereferences `ptr` leading to the first subarray. Then, `[1]` gets the second element from the first subarray which is 2. Similarly, `(*ptr)[2]` first dereferences `ptr` leading to the first subarray. Then, `[2]` gets the third element from the first subarray which is 3.

Next,

```
++ptr;
```

increments `ptr` which implies that now, it points to the address of the second subarray. So now, `(*ptr)[1]` first dereferences `ptr` leading to the second subarray. Then, `[1]` gets the second element from the second subarray which is 4. Similarly, `(*ptr)[2]` first dereferences `ptr` leading to the second subarray. Then, `[2]` gets the third element from the second subarray which is 5.

Now,

```
ptr++;
```

further increments `ptr` which means that it now points to a memory addess *past* the second subarray or the 2D array. After this, dereferncing the pointer as in `(*ptr)[1]` and `(*ptr)[2]` invokes *Undefined Behavior* as you are reading invalid memory addresses past the array.

Finally,

> is it means that `(*ptr)[1]` is equal to `ptr[0][1]` and `(*ptr)[2]` means `ptr[0][2]`?

Yes. Correct.

Comment: You're welcome! It is encouraged to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if an answer answers your question.